# Show Percentage of work accomplished on Progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I need to show the **percentage** of the work done by method DoLongWork() in a **Progressbar** using the thread.

```
Public string  DoLongWork(int varName)
{
      Thread.Sleep(1000000);

       /*This method will take 1 hour to return the result (say)*/
      Return "Done";
 }
```

DoLongWork() method will do the backup of a database.You know which will take more time to perform the database backup and I need to show the percentage of backup taken on progressbar.Thanks

Any type of suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're actually doing a Thread.Sleep(1000000) in this thread I don't think there's any way to let progress bar know how long it's been asleep for like this. But if you've actually some loop going in this thread you need to use a `delegate` to update your Progressbar if it's in the UI thread.

Comment: This question has already been there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623923/progress-bar-and-backgroundworker-in-c-sharp

Comment: @ judgeja:DoLongWork() method will do the backup of a database.You know which will take more time to perform the database backup and I need to show the percentage of backup taken on progressbar.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) which will report on the progress that has elapsed. A small example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Start a new worker
/// </summary>
void StartWork()
{
    var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    //make sure the worker reports on progress
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    //we want to get notified when progress has changed
    backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged+=backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;

    //here we do the work
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;

}

void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //do long work
}

ProgressBar _progressBar = new ProgressBar();
void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //when we are notified about progress changed, update the progressbar
    _progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For what you want to do I would recommend a background worker to do the method and give functionality to check the state of the progress bar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: DoLongWork() method will do the backup of a database.You know which will take more time to perform the database backup and I need to show the percentage of backup taken on progressbar.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question, but I assume you are referring to how to manage the threads, and that you are probably using WinForms?

If so:

- Execute your "DoLongWork" function on a background (or non-UI) thread. There are various ways to do this, including using the ThreadPool class, or creating a new Thread object that refers to your method and calls Start() on it
- Periodically during the work being done in DoLongWork (ie. maybe once each time through a loop?), post the progress figure back to the UI thread, so that it can be rendered on the progress bar control. This is required because changes to controls must occur on the UI thread. Look at the Control.Invoke and Control.BeginInvoke methods for doing this

You may also want to reconsider whether your DoLongWork method has a return value. 
If it's running on a separate thread, I'm not sure that the return value will have anywhere to go... the normal approach would be for it to store it's result somewhere, so that it can be retrieved by the logic that runs when the work is finished. Assuming something happens in the UI when it's finished, this could be a separate method that gets invoked on the UI thread by DoLongWork making another Invoke/BeginInvoke call as its last step.

Comment: Yes, am using Winform and want to know how to mange the thread. and There is no loop present for the DoLongWork method.It will just return value after 1 hour (say)

Comment: Is there any way to measure the progress then? If it's just a single very long IO call, you might need to just estimate the duration, and have an algorithm for slowing it if the task runs over. If you do it this way, you could use a System.Timers.Timer object to trigger your progress bar updates periodically, in it's Elapsed event. You would still execute your work method on a non-ui thread as described above, and invoke some method on the ui thread when it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using a background worker to update your progress bar

here is an example [Background worker with progress bar](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo)